# Change Default Config Settings for PHP?

Tags: linux, php, unix

When setting up php on a new Unix-based server, are there any default PHP settings that you will always change? Any that you will always consider changing based on the particular environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A default installation of PHP on a UNIX server pretty much works out of the box. Much of the configuration depends on your desired usage of the server.

Here's what I do:

- Change `upload_max_filesize` from the default value (2M) to something higher.
- Install and enable the modules that I use most often:

  - php5-gd
  - php5-cli
  - php5-suhosin
  - php5-curl

But again: most of the configuration is dependent on what you use the server for, which makes it hard to provide a simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't something that I *always* change. Actually, there's rarely anything I change, for *any given installation*.

If it's my own for-development-and-play-server, I probably max out the permissions to do anything, but when deploying a server for something specific, I want to have the PHP as strict as possible, without affecting the functionality of the scripts too much.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling magic quotes is one of the first things that I do.  It does nothing but cause problems and introduce a false sense of security.  I'm clueless to why its on by default.